# Capture the string from a camera.Getpicture

Tags: html, cordova, camera, base64

In the phonegap docs

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

the ONLY examples given with the base 64 string is

Render the image in an  tag (see example below)

and I cannot after days of searching and trying to figure it out get the string itself so i can either

Save the data locally (LocalStorage)
Post the data to a remote server

please can someone advise how to capture the image and actually get hold of the base64 output so I can use it. I am pretty much using the basic code from the example

i,e

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Thank you in advance for ANY assitance.. I am losing a lot of sleep over this.. the console log only shows a tiny capture.. which cant be a full image

Comment: Eh? The string is passed to onSuccess. You have the string right there as "imageData."

Comment: I thought as much, based on the last tests last night where I was getting

request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)

when I was posting that exact string.. 

I am only taking a 640 x 480 picture.. how am I supposed to POST a string that is always going to be long without my script on the remote server throwing up this error

Comment: So to be clear - you are sending the value via POST and your server is barfing? That seems extreme. Can you show how you doing the POST?

Comment: @RaymondCamden sorry having issues with the inline formating. Put all relevant code pieces in [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1j0zvhpbqx5wwsq/codesample.rtf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing your post data is incorrect. You are sending it as a string. Instead of doing data:'make a big ole string', you want: data:{name:value, name2:value}, etc. Also, in the future, I'd recommend Pastebin.com to share your code instead of an RTF file. Quicker. :)

Comment: yeah, got it figured last night, it was badly incorrect.. not sure what planet I was on. Appreciate you taking the time to answer. Now posting base64 code to my remote server with ease.. now just to reconstruct it =)